# Swift - Without storyboard , how do I make a modal popup?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I didn't use a storyboard and I'm having trouble finding resources on programmatically making a modal popup ( it'll be a form with white background that takes up the bottom half of the screen) after you press a button. The previous view would be disabled until you exit out of this modal popup.

Would this modal popup have its own view and view controller? How would I make the popup appear and after you exit, you give the control back to the original view controller?

Thanks?

Answer (score 2):

```
let rateViewController = RatePopupVC()

rateViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
rateViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
rateViewController.item = item // In case you want to transfer some data
self.present(rateViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would this modal popup have its own view and view controller

Yes. Configure your view controller and its view, and present it with `present` and dismiss it with `dismiss`. You can add custom transition animation and custom positioning of the view.

Comment: Elaborate example here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: is there a more updated resource where it's in swift and they don't use a storyboard?

Comment: The example is in Swift, is up to date, and doesn't use a storyboard for the modal popup.